# Где ошибка в вычислении корней квадратного уравнения ?

Tags: java

Для примера возьмём `а = 2, b = 6, c = 3`. Моя программа выдаёт корни `-5.133974596215562` и `-6.866025403784438`. А калькулятор `-0,633974` и `2,366025`. Где ошибка в моих расчётах, или я неправильно записал формулу ?

```
package kostin4_3;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;
public class start {
    static double a =0; static double b=0; static double c=0; static double d=0; static double x1=0; static double x2=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Dano();
     Calc();
    }
    private static void Calc() {
        d = (Math.pow(b, 2)) - (4*a*c);
        System.out.print("Ваш дискриминант = " + d);
        System.out.println();
        if (d < 0) {
            System.out.print("У вашего квадратного уравнения нет корней!");
            System.out.println();
        } if (d == 0) {
            x1=-(b/(2*a));
            System.out.print("У вашего один корень равный " + x1);
            System.out.println();
        }  else 
        {
            x1=((-b + (Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)));
            x2=((-b - (Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)));
            System.out.print("Первый корень вашего уравнения равен " + x1);
            System.out.println()     ;
            System.out.print("Второй корень вашего уравнения равен " + x2);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void Dano(){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Введите первый член выражения! (не ноль)!");
            a = scn.nextDouble();
                if (a !=0) {
                    System.out.print("Ваш первый член выражения = " + a);
                } else { System.out.print("Ну просили же не ноль!"); }
            } while (a == 0);
            System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Введите второй член выражения! ");
                b = scn.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Ваш второй член выражения = " + b);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Введите третий член выражения! ");
                c = scn.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Ваш третий член выражения = " + c);
                System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас неправильно расставлены скобки:

```
x1=((-b + (Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)));
x2=((-b - (Math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)));
```

если убрать лишние, то это

```
x1= -b + Math.sqrt(d)/(2*a);
x2= -b - Math.sqrt(d)/(2*a);
```

а должно быть

```
x1= (-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a);
x2= (-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2*a);
```